# Append a text file starting from a certain location in the source text file

Tags: c#, .net, string, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to append a text file (let's say "append.txt") in another text file (let's say "original.txt") but not at last line/character of "original.txt". It should append starting from a certain location of a string (let's say "match") found in "original.txt". And ignore all other text in "original.txt" after "match" string's location and start appending the "append.txt" file from the "match" string's location in the "original.txt" file.

The problems that I face are:

1. I can not load whole files in memory because the files can go up to 100 MB. So, I have decided to use StreamReader and StreamWriter and use ReadLine and WriteLine for line by line append and to get the location of target string in a line to find out from where to start the append process. Is this the best approach?
2. I would prefer not to use a third temporary file (let's say "temporary.txt") to have final text and then replace "original.txt" with "temporary.txt" because of the large file size transfer. Is it possible to not use a third temporary file?

My current code is:

```
StreamReader TextFile = new StreamReader("original.txt");
StreamReader TextFileAppend = new StreamReader("append.txt");
StreamWriter TextFileTemp = new StreamWriter("temporary.txt");

sLine = TextFile.ReadLine();

while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine) && !TextFile.EndOfStream && !sLine.Contains("match"))
{
    TextFileTemp.WriteLine(sLine);
    sLine = TextFile.ReadLine();
    TextFileTemp.WriteLine(sLine);
}

TextFile.Close();

sLine = TextFileAppend.ReadLine();

while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine) && !TextFileAppend.EndOfStream)
{
    sLine = TextFileAppend.ReadLine();
    TextFileTemp.WriteLine(sLine);
}

TextFileTemp.Close();
TextFileAppend.Close();

File.Copy("temporary.txt", "original.txt", true);
```

The above code works fine but requires a temporary third file to save the merged content and then replaces "original.txt" with the merged text file.

There is nothing wrong in the code but I was wondering if a file can be appended from a certain location and not from the end?

Comment: What's wrong with a temporary file?  Seems like a good idea incase someone fails between when you start coping and before it finishes...

Comment: @PeterRitchie  No, nothing wrong but I was wondering if a file can be appended from a certain location and not the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, 100 Mb is not out of the range of reading in the entire file contents into a string and then using the in memory functions to go faster. What's important is that manipulating large strings like that may be slow.

Try this:

```
string originalContents = File.ReadAllText("original.txt");
string insertContents = File.ReadAllText("append.txt");
int index = originalContents .IndexOf("match");
if (index == -1) return;
FileStream stream = new FileStream("original.txt", FileMode.Open);
stream.Position = index;
byte[] insertBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(insertContents);
stream.Write(insertBytes);
byte[] endBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(originalContents.Substring(index));
stream.Write(endBytes);
```

Comment: Will code: File.ReadAllText("original.txt") not increase the process's memory required to 100 MB?

Comment: Yes it will. Are your memory constraints really that tight? What are you trying to insert in the middle of a file for anyway? There isn't really a way to insert into a file. You will have to overwrite one part with the inserted data, and copy all the old data to the its position plus the length of the insert. You can build on my answer to have it cycle through the file.